# Can an individual Git Repo's directories be locked down to different users?

Tags: git, github

I would like to setup a private Git Repo for a Client/Server project.  The catch is, only allowing designated users read-commit to either the Client or Server code of the Repo based on their role within the project:

```
+ Project Repo
  + Client (Only accessible to Client Developers)
  + Server (Only accessible to Server Developers)
```

Is this feature supported in Git, or do I need to breakout the source into 2 separate repos for Client & Server?

```
+ Client Project Repo (Only accessible to Client Developers)
+ Server Project Repo (Only accessible to Server Developers)
```

I'm reading about Git Submodules, but I don't believe they will support my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do I need to breakout the source into 2 separate repos for Client & Server?

That is the safest route if you want to be sure to limit access/visibility to *part* of one repo: having two repos with a clear list of contributors means one population cannot access the repo it is not a contributor to.

[Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) can help admins cloning only the repo `Project`, which would reference the repos `Client` and the repo `Server`:

```
git clone --recursive
```

That way, an admin can keep at all time track of which version of the Client goes with a version of the Server.

Comment: Migrating from TFS that doesn't support it, I figured the same for Git.  I'm setting up Jira/BitBucket, so the draw back from multiple repos is they will not be managed under one Jira project.  Appears Jira projects have a single 1-to-1 relation with a BitBucket Git Repo, but my repos will be secure based on the ACL structure I require which is more important.

Comment: @CampbellGolf True: if you need to have both repos into one for Jira, you can use subtrees: http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/